# Scala scalikejdbc select query to return a map

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, dictionary

I have a query that does some aggregations that looks like this

```
  override def getMinMax(products: Seq[Product]): List[(String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal)] = {
    val ids = productsToSqlString(products)
    DB readOnly { implicit session =>
      sql"""SELECT id, min(p_discount_rate), max(p_discount_rate)
            |FROM ${Product.table}
            |WHERE p_config_sku IN ${configSkus} AND p_is_deleted IS FALSE
            |GROUP BY id
            """.stripMargin
        .map(rs => rs.string(1) -> (BigDecimal(rs.string(2)), BigDecimal(rs.string(3)))).toMap.list.apply

    }
```

I would like this to return a map of Ids to tuples of bigdecimals (discount rates) I am not really sure how to achieve that

Best.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.breakOut    

val myData: List[(String, BigDecimal, BigDecimal)] = ???

val myMap: Map[String, (BigDecimal, BigDecimal)] = myData.map{ case (id, t1, t2) => id -> (t1 -> t2) }(breakOut)
```